# Cleaning and sealing tile grout

Tags: tile

In our kitchen, the tile grout has gotten a little dirty.  It isn't bad, but you can definitely tell that certain spots are *changing their color* a little bit.

Is there a way to do a *very* deep clean on the grout (bleach it?) and then seal it so that in the future this isn't an issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, if your tile grout is light colored and the dark areas are of an organic makeup (coffee, gravy, etc.), bleach will clean and brighten the grout. I believe it is applied full strength with a paint brush and allowed to soak-in for several minutes. Agitating with a stiff bristle brush will loosen any surface stains. Wipe up remaining bleach with a dry rag and than wipe with a rag that's been lightly wrung of clean water. Dry with a towel.

Comment: Ok perfect thank you! And then just use a grout sealer after that?

Comment: Absolutely. I believe the grout should be free of any discoloration and stains otherwise they will be 'locked in' by the sealer. Another suggestion is to seal it with an appropriate colored dye:  http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1/179-2501037-5341711?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=grout+paint&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Agrout+paint .